# How to plot multiple figures in a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

I wish to implement a for loop that would perform short time fourier series. I'll be using windowing and say I obtain 3 frames on which i wish to perform fft inside a for loop, how can i plot all three graphs?

> pos = (1+w_length:w_length:length(wave))-w_length;
>
> for v = pos
>
> data_sub = wave(v:v+w_length);
>
> ```
> subsection_fft = fft(data_sub);
> ```
>
> end

Answer (score 2):

You can create new figures by using the `figure` function.

```
  figure
  plot([0 1],[0 .3]);

  figure
  plot([0 1],[0 0.6]);

  figure
  plot([0 1],[0 0.9]);
```

Or you can put multiple axes in the same figure using the `subplot` function;

```
  subplot(3,1,1);
  plot([0 1],[0 .3]);

  subplot(3,1,2);
  plot([0 1],[0 .6]);

  subplot(3,1,3);
  plot([0 1],[0 .9]);
```

Or you can plot 3 lines in the same axis by using the `hold` function

```
  plot([0 1],[0 .3]);
  hold on;

  plot([0 1],[0 .6]);

  plot([0 1],[0 .9]);
```